# Missing static routing in VPN Connection (VPN server + RPi + subnet)

Tags: networking, vpn, synology

I have two networks that are connected via VPN. I have an OpenVPN server running on my NAS at home. Outside my network I have a Raspberry Pi (RPi) which is connected to my local network via VPN. The RPi connects to the internet using WiFi (wlan1). This all works fine.

Now I would like to connect a camera to the RPi using ethernet (eth0) and store the stream directly on the NAS. I have created a new network profile for eth0 on the Rpi and set "Shared to other computer" there. The network between the RPi and the camera is 10.42.0.0/24. The camera is accessible from the RPi and everything works fine. When I try to ping (10.42.0.231) the camera from my NAS, where the VPN server is running and the recording will be running, the camera is unavailable.

[image: Image of network architecture]

Interfaces on the NAS and routing table:

```
$ip a
5: ovs_eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc htb state UP group default qlen 1
    link/ether 00:11:32:aa:84:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.142/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global ovs_eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: tun1000: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1400 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 169.254.124.128/21 scope global tun1000
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         router.lan      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ovs_eth0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
169.254.120.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     0      0        0 tun1000
169.254.120.0   169.254.120.1   255.255.248.0   UG    0      0        0 tun1000
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ovs_eth0

$ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev ovs_eth0  src 192.168.1.142 
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0 
10.8.0.2 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.1 
169.254.120.0/21 dev tun1000  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.124.128 
169.254.120.0/21 via 169.254.120.1 dev tun1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev ovs_eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.142
```

Interfaces on the RPi and routing table:

```
$ip a
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:9c:d9:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.42.0.1/24 brd 10.42.0.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:de:d0:05:8d:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.220.34/24 brd 192.168.220.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan1
       valid_lft 3448sec preferred_lft 3448sec
6: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.10 peer 10.8.0.9/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.220.15  0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan1
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.9        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.1        10.8.0.9        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.9        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     10.8.0.9        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.220.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan1

$ip route
default via 192.168.220.15 dev wlan1 proto dhcp src 192.168.220.34 metric 600 
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.9 dev tun0 
10.8.0.1 via 10.8.0.9 dev tun0 
10.8.0.9 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.10 
10.42.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.42.0.1 metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 via 10.8.0.9 dev tun0 
192.168.220.0/24 dev wlan1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.220.34 metric 600
```

According to me it should be enough to just add a static route to the NAS, but that didn't help me, is there a bug in my entry or is there something else I need to configure? Thank you for any help.

Comment: `When I try to ping (10.42.0.231) the camera from my NAS, where the VPN server is running and the recording will be running, the camera is unavailable.` when you run a packet capture on the rpi, does it show the ping coming in and going out to the camera? And no response from the camera due to no return route?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need *at least* either of these:

- DNAT (a.k.a. Port Forwarding) on the RPi
- an `iroute` in the client config directory (ccd) file for the RPi on your OpenVPN server

---

If you choose DNAT, you would not need any extra route on your NAS, because the necessary route (the one for `10.8.0.0/24`, as you can see) has already been added by OpenVPN when the server is started.

To set up the DNAT, you should probably run something like:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -p tcp_or_udp --dport some_port -j DNAT --to-destination 10.42.0.231
```

You would be accessing the camera with RPi's VPN IP (`10.8.0.10`) if you choose DNAT.

---

If you choose `iroute`, you would at the same time need to add a corresponding route (same destination and netmask / prefix length) on the NAS. For example:

```
ip route add 10.42.0.231 dev tun0
```

The route is for routing the corresponding traffics into the tunnel, while the `iroute` is for the OpenVPN server to know which client the traffics should go to. By default (i.e., without any `iroute`) it only knows where the traffics should go if the destination is a VPN client's address (which is why DNAT can be an alternative).

See the OpenVPN manual for details regarding `iroute` and ccd (file).

---

For both choices, you'll need to make sure the the camera's default gateway (more precisely, the gateway used for traffics destined at `10.8.0.1`) is `10.42.0.1`. If you can't have such route with such gateway on the camera, you should set up source NAT on the RPi. For example:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

---

Also, both choices requires IP forwarding to be enabled (sysctl) and allowed (firewall) on the RPi.